# Not unique table/alias: IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT customer.Costumer_name
FROM Customer,Product,Order1,Order_line
    INNER JOIN Order1 ON  Order1.Order_ID = customer.Costumer_ID
    INNER JOIN Order_line ON Order_line.Order_ID = Product.Product_ID;
```

why the error like this > ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'Order1'

Comment: Try Order1 as OrderOne in From

Comment: nothing happen bruh

Comment: True - for some reason you decided to have order1 and order_line defined in both an implicit and explicit join. BTW you should not mix implicit and explicit joins ' If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html , I would urge you not to use implicit joins at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer.Costumer_name
    FROM Customer,Product
INNER JOIN Order1 
   ON  Order1.Order_ID = customer.Costumer_ID
INNER JOIN Order_line 
   ON Order_line.Order_ID = Product.Product_ID;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain it..